# vault token create after vault login -method ldap

Tags: ldap, terraform, hashicorp-vault, pulumi

Vault version 1.5.2

My end goal is to use Vault in some Terraform code to retrieve temporary credentials. The issue is Terraform will always generate a new child token even if the current token is a 5 minute token. This means the current VAULT_TOKEN must be some sort of super root token because I've tried logging in with the LDAP backend and it doesn't matter which policies or token roles I try to use it seems I can't ever generate new tokens.

To replicate what Terraform is doing:

```
vault login -address vault.example -ca-cert ca.pem -method ldap -path ldap_users user=botman
Couldn't start vault with IPC_LOCK. Disabling IPC_LOCK, please use --privileged or --cap-add IPC_LOCK
Password (will be hidden):
s.<token>
```

I have all of the permission as defined by the policies and everything seems fine.

Now try to create a child token:

```
vault token create -address vault.example -ca-cert ca.pem -role superrole
Error creating token: Error making API request.

URL: POST https://vault.example/v1/auth/token/create/superrole
Code: 400. Errors:

* restricted use token cannot generate child tokens
```

Remove the `-role` parameter and we get the same error.

I've tried looking everywhere to see what I'm missing, but the only token that can create child tokens seems to be the root token.

I apologize if I missed something very simple.

An example policy that I have attached (I've tried many polices but this one seems the most extreme)

```
path "auth/*" {
  capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list", "sudo"]
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

I took the time to setup some approles to test this out. I added the exact same policies as the LDAP backend. With the approle I can get a token and then create new tokens from the initial token. I took a look at the LDAP documentation to see if I missed somewhere that says you can't create child tokens from tokens originating from LDAP and I couldn't find anything: https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/ldap.html

EDIT2:

Pulumi config for the LDAP Auth Backend

```
    return vault.ldap.AuthBackend(
        resource_name="vault-ldap-{}".format(ldap.name),
        binddn=bind_dn,
        bindpass=bind_pass,
        certificate=cert,
        description=ldap.desc,
        discoverdn=False,
        groupattr="cn",
        groupdn=ldap.groupdn,
        groupfilter="(&(objectClass=group)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={{.UserDN}}))",
        insecure_tls=False,
        path="ldap_{}".format(ldap.name),
        starttls=False,
        tls_max_version="tls12",
        tls_min_version="tls10",
        token_explicit_max_ttl=14 * 60 * 60 * 24,
        token_max_ttl=7 * 60 * 60 * 24,
        token_num_uses=56,
        url=url,
        userattr="samaccountname",
        userdn=ldap.userdn,
        opts=opts,
    )
```

Comment: Can you show the details of the token from LDAP? Do you have any restrictions on it like `token_num_uses`? And what is the configuration of your LDAP engine?

Comment: token_num uses looks like 56. I pasted the pulumi block I used to create the LDAP backends. I think most of the variables aren't relevant but can give an example of expanded use if needed.

Comment: From [this discussion](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/restricted-use-token-cannot-generate-child-tokens/10748/2), it looks like having `token_num_uses` set to something non-zero will prevent the token from creating child tokens

Comment: The reason it is broken for LDAP and working for AppRole is because the LDAP backend is applying the `token_num_uses` property, whereas I'm guessing the AppRole backend is not

Comment: @lxop that was the fix. Can you add an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see your LDAP backend is setting `token_num_uses`. From [this documentation](https://www.vaultproject.io/api/auth/ldap#token_num_uses) and [this discussion](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/restricted-use-token-cannot-generate-child-tokens/10748/2), having `token_num_uses` set to something non-zero will prevent the token from creating child tokens.

The reason it is broken for LDAP and working for AppRole is because the LDAP backend is applying the `token_num_uses` property, whereas I'm guessing the AppRole backend is not.